# What is the error when creating a table in the clickhouse = SummingMergeTree engine?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to create a table in clickhouse directly from the documentation. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/summingmergetree/#usage-example

`[2023-03-10 11:11:43] Code: 223. DB::Exception: [value] is not an identifier. (UNEXPECTED_AST_STRUCTURE) (version 23.2.3.17 (official build)) [2023-03-10 11:11:43] , server ClickHouseNode [uri=http://localhost:51584/default, options={custom_http_params=session_id=DataGrip_944476ca-188b-451f-ba27-d2265ff05354}]@-1702792093`

trying to create a table in clickhouse directly from the documentation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Documentation: `[ ]` -- means optional parameters. Not ARRAYS.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form  `optional  [ ... ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example. Rows with the same primary key collapse into one row, and numeric columns are automatically summed together. (For non-numeric columns, a random value is picked).

You definitely don't want the square brackets...

```
CREATE TABLE smt (
    id UInt32,
    x UInt32,
    y UInt32,
    z String
)
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree
PRIMARY KEY id;

INSERT INTO smt VALUES 
   (1, 10, 100, 'Hello'),
   (1, 20, 200, 'Goodbye'),
   (2, 30, 300, 'Hi'),
   (2, 40, 400, 'Bye');

SELECT *
FROM smt

Query id: dad88e93-5d4a-4a8c-8342-46e9d93cf02a

┌─id─┬──x─┬───y─┬─z─────┐
│  1 │ 30 │ 300 │ Hello │
│  2 │ 70 │ 700 │ Hi    │
└────┴────┴─────┴───────┘

2 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.007 sec.
```